# Does 'Recycle Bin' storage affect roaming profile space?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, roaming-profile

Our company allocates 40MB space for profile storage on the server. A user has a file of 15MB in his Recycle Bin which was deleted from his Desktop. In the past few weeks this user noticed a message about his roaming profile not being loaded after signing in on his computer. After clearing the Recycle Bin and restarting the system the profile message is not shown.

Is it possible that files in the Recycle Bin account for profile space, especially when they've been deleted from the Desktop which is part of the profile.

*(AFAIK Recycle Bin doesn't physically delete files it only removes the headers to those files, meaning that a file takes up just as much physical space regardless of being in Recycle Bin or not)*

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you explicitely modified the default settings, it shouldn't do so since is not a part of the roamed folders (%UserProfile%\Appdata\Roaming).